# Is this piecewise function continuous on $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, continuity

OK so I have this function $f(x)=\begin{cases} x,& x<0
 \\x+1, &  x\geq0
\end{cases}$.

It's clearly not continuous at all points. But I somehow find that its left-hand and right-hand derivatives at $0$ are $f'_{-}(0)=f'_{+}(0)=1$, which means $f$ is differentiable at all points and therefore is continous at all points.

Could you please point out my mistake?

Comment: No, it does not exist $\;f’_{-}(0)\;$

Comment: For $x<0$ we have $ \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}= \frac{x-1}{x}.$ Hence $ \lim_{x \to 0-0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}$ does not exists, so $f'_{-}(0)$ does not exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$f_-'(0)=\lim_{h\to 0^-}\frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0^-}\frac{h-1}{h}\ne 1$$

Comment: This answers my question. I miscalculated the left-hand derivative. Thanks sir!

Answer (score 2):

The result that if the one sided limits of $f'$ at $0$ exist, then $f'(0)$ exists, only holds for continuous $f$, because it needs the mean value Theorem.

Comment: Look at Fred’s comment and jjagmath’s answer. Actually $\;f’_{-}(0)\;$ does not exist.

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding here. What I think what Math Learner means is that if $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} f(x)$ exists, then $f'(0)$ exists and hence $f$ is continuous. But this result only holds if $f$ is continuous.

Comment: No, I think what the OP means is that $f’_{-}(0)=f’_{+}(0)=1$ implies that $f$ is differentiable and continuous at $0$. But, actually  $f’_{-}(0)$ does not exist, so it is false that $f$ is differentiable at $0$. Read the OP’s comment in jjagmath’s answer. He believed that $f’_{-}(0)=1$.

Comment: Yes. Thank you, this ist clear now